# Can't connect to monero daemon on my LAN

Tags: mining

I have monerod running on a computer in my LAN, let's pretend the local IP is 10.0.0.9. I want to mine with another computer on the same LAN but not have to download the whole chain. So I run the wallet CLI on another computer, like this:

```
./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-host 10.0.0.9
```

but in addition to giving me warnings about using an untrusted daemon, it throws the error that the wallet failed to connect to it.

There's no firewall running on the computer running monerod, and both machines are on the same subnet.

What I would really like is to have a way to just have the other computers mine on behalf of the wallet on my self-managed node. I don't understand why the other computers also need wallets in order to mine. But that might be neither here nor there, since I can't connect to my daemon anyway.

Comment: Perhaps update/edit your question with the exact warnings and errors shown by your wallet.

Comment: You have to set up your node as remote node (even if the node runs on the same network). You can ensure the node is only privately accessible. See: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6145/how-to-connect-to-my-own-remote-node

Comment: add port <ip>:<port>

Comment: Thanks. What I needed was to add `--rpc-bind-ip [node IP] --confirm-external-bind` to the daemon command itself. Also this made the local wallet stop working and I had to start the wallet again with `[node IP] --trusted-daemon` added on.

But actually this entire question was under the false impression that I could mine without a local daemon. Was trying to conserve storage across my PCs, not to mention the days it takes to sync in the first place.